# How to make sound works on Mozilla Firefox 52?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, alsa, pulseaudio, lubuntu

I use Lubuntu, which I believe does not use pulse-audio, or uses a container for that, I do not know, but it seems to use alsa well.

Since I upgrade to Firefox 52, which does not accept plugins anymore, the sound stoped working, and it shows a tip to fix that, but when I click on it, the site does not exist anymore.

How can I fix the sound on Firefox 52 without replacing alsa?

[image: youtobe requires sound]

[image: tip do not exists]

Comment: cross post http://askubuntu.com/q/892263/350004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just instal pulse audio `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pavucontrol`

Comment: The sound worked on qemu with pulseaudio installed, although I was not what I wanted to do, I will wait for Firefox working with alsa.

Comment: Doesn't work. On my site it is installed but FF thinks it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

This will kill FireFox for Linux users. However: FireFox HAS SOUND without Pulseaudio (PA), as is shown by YouTube!!! How? Go to your Channel, Video Manager and select Edit -> Audio, then play your selected video....
This gives a clue that FF has a "bug", possibly an oversight in its Preferences.